Gazebo crash with the error ODE INTERNAL ERROR 1
I am using Gazebo Harmonic with ROS2 Jazzy in Ubuntu 24.04. 
I encounter the following errors when trying to start the simulation:
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] ODE INTERNAL ERROR 1: assertion "aabbBound >= dMinIntExact && aabbBound < dMaxIntExact" failed in collide() [collision_space.cpp:460]
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] Stack trace (most recent call last):
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] #31   Object "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-3.2.so.3.2", at 0x7f0d424fb8ef, in 
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] #30   Object "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-3.2.so.3.2", at 0x7f0d4243c099, in 
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] #29   Object "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-3.2.so.3.2", at 0x7f0d42365216, in rb_protect
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] #28   Object "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-3.2.so.3.2", at 0x7f0d4250a2c9, in rb_yield
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] #27   Object "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-3.2.so.3.2", at 0x7f0d42505b39, in rb_vm_exec
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] #26   Object "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-3.2.so.3.2", at 0x7f0d425025db, in 
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] #25   Object "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-3.2.so.3.2", at 0x7f0d424fe0fe, in 
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] #24   Object "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-3.2.so.3.2", at 0x7f0d424fb8ef, in 
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] #23   Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/3.2.0/fiddle.so", at 0x7f0d3d3b7b13, in 
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] #22   Object "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-3.2.so.3.2", at 0x7f0d424c43bb, in rb_nogvl
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] #21   Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/3.2.0/fiddle.so", at 0x7f0d3d3b743b, in 
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] #20   Object "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.8", at 0x7f0d3d3520bd, in ffi_call
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] #19   Object "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.8", at 0x7f0d3d34f3ee, in 
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] #18   Object "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.8", at 0x7f0d3d352b15, in 
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] #17   Object "/opt/ros/jazzy/opt/gz_sim_vendor/lib/libgz-sim8-gz.so.8.6.0", at 0x7f0d3c8358ff, in runServer
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] #16   Object "/opt/ros/jazzy/opt/gz_sim_vendor/lib/libgz-sim8.so.8", at 0x7f0d3c541fa7, in 
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] #15   Object "/opt/ros/jazzy/opt/gz_sim_vendor/lib/libgz-sim8.so.8", at 0x7f0d3c5506e6, in gz::sim::v8::SimulationRunner::Run(unsigned long)
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] #14   Object "/opt/ros/jazzy/opt/gz_sim_vendor/lib/libgz-sim8.so.8", at 0x7f0d3c54fd41, in gz::sim::v8::SimulationRunner::Step(gz::sim::v8::UpdateInfo const&)
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] #13   Object "/opt/ros/jazzy/opt/gz_sim_vendor/lib/libgz-sim8.so.8", at 0x7f0d3c54df63, in gz::sim::v8::SimulationRunner::UpdateSystems()
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] #12   Object "/opt/ros/jazzy/opt/gz_sim_vendor/lib/gz-sim-8/plugins/libgz-sim-physics-system.so", at 0x7f0d305bbfef, in gz::sim::v8::systems::Physics::Update(gz::sim::v8::UpdateInfo const&, gz::sim::v8::EntityComponentManager&)
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] #11   Object "/opt/ros/jazzy/opt/gz_sim_vendor/lib/gz-sim-8/plugins/libgz-sim-physics-system.so", at 0x7f0d305c1c85, in gz::sim::v8::systems::PhysicsPrivate::Step(std::chrono::duration<long, std::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > const&)
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] #10   Object "/opt/ros/jazzy/opt/gz_physics_vendor/lib/gz-physics-7/engine-plugins/libgz-physics-dartsim-plugin.so", at 0x7f0d1416ec92, in gz::physics::dartsim::SimulationFeatures::WorldForwardStep(gz::physics::Identity const&, gz::physics::SpecifyData<gz::physics::RequireData<gz::physics::WorldPoses>, gz::physics::ExpectData<gz::physics::ChangedWorldPoses, gz::physics::Contacts, gz::physics::JointPositions> >&, gz::physics::CompositeData&, gz::physics::ExpectData<gz::physics::ApplyExternalForceTorques, gz::physics::ApplyGeneralizedForces, gz::physics::VelocityControlCommands, gz::physics::ServoControlCommands, std::chrono::duration<long, std::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > > const&)
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] #9    Object "/opt/ros/jazzy/opt/gz_dartsim_vendor/lib/libdart.so.6.13", at 0x7f0d13e1a98c, in dart::simulation::World::step(bool)
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] #8    Object "/opt/ros/jazzy/opt/gz_dartsim_vendor/lib/libdart.so.6.13", at 0x7f0d13e06c25, in dart::constraint::ConstraintSolver::solve()
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] #7    Object "/opt/ros/jazzy/opt/gz_dartsim_vendor/lib/libdart.so.6.13", at 0x7f0d13e049c0, in dart::constraint::ConstraintSolver::updateConstraints()
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] #6    Object "/opt/ros/jazzy/opt/gz_physics_vendor/lib/gz-physics-7/engine-plugins/libgz-physics-dartsim-plugin.so", at 0x7f0d1414e59b, in dart::collision::GzOdeCollisionDetector::collide(dart::collision::CollisionGroup*, dart::collision::CollisionOption const&, dart::collision::CollisionResult*)
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] #5    Object "/opt/ros/jazzy/opt/gz_dartsim_vendor/lib/libdart-collision-ode.so.6.13", at 0x7f0d13f7e48c, in dart::collision::OdeCollisionDetector::collide(dart::collision::CollisionGroup*, dart::collision::CollisionOption const&, dart::collision::CollisionResult*)
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] #4    Object "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libode.so.8", at 0x7f0d13902259, in dxHashSpace::collide(void*, void (*)(void*, dxGeom*, dxGeom*))
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] #3    Object "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libode.so.8", at 0x7f0d13901037, in dDebug
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] #2    Object "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", at 0x7f0d41eff8fe, in abort
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] #1    Object "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", at 0x7f0d41f1c26d, in gsignal
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] #0    Object "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", at 0x7f0d41f75b1c, in pthread_kill
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] Aborted (Signal sent by tkill() 17689 1002)


This is my world file:
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<sdf version="1.8">
  <world name="empty">
    <plugin
      filename="gz-sim-physics-system"
      name="gz::sim::systems::Physics">
    </plugin>
    <plugin
      filename="gz-sim-sensors-system"
      name="gz::sim::systems::Sensors">
      <render_engine>ogre2</render_engine>
    </plugin>
    <plugin
      filename="gz-sim-scene-broadcaster-system"
      name="gz::sim::systems::SceneBroadcaster">
    </plugin>
    <plugin
      filename="gz-sim-user-commands-system"
      name="gz::sim::systems::UserCommands">
    </plugin>

    <light name="sun" type="directional">
      <cast_shadows>true</cast_shadows>
      <pose>0 0 10 0 0 0</pose>
      <diffuse>0.8 0.8 0.8 1</diffuse>
      <specular>0.2 0.2 0.2 1</specular>
      <attenuation>
        <range>1000</range>
        <constant>0.9</constant>
        <linear>0.01</linear>
        <quadratic>0.001</quadratic>
      </attenuation>
      <direction>-0.5 0.1 -0.9</direction>
    </light>

    <model name="ground_plane">
      <static>true</static>
      <link name="link">
        <collision name="collision">
          <geometry>
            <plane>
              <normal>0 0 1</normal>
              <size>100 100</size>
            </plane>
          </geometry>
        </collision>
        <visual name="visual">
          <geometry>
            <plane>
              <normal>0 0 1</normal>
              <size>100 100</size>
            </plane>
          </geometry>
          <material>
            <ambient>0.8 0.8 0.8 1</ambient>
            <diffuse>0.8 0.8 0.8 1</diffuse>
            <specular>0.8 0.8 0.8 1</specular>
          </material>
        </visual>
      </link>
    </model>

    <model name="my_robot">
      <self_collide>true</self_collide>
      <pose>0 0 0.35 0 0 0</pose>
      <include merge="true">
        <uri>package://my_robot/models/my_robot</uri>
      </include>

      <plugin
        filename="gz-sim-joint-state-publisher-system"
        name="gz::sim::systems::JointStatePublisher">
      </plugin>

      <plugin
        filename="gz-sim-pose-publisher-system"
        name="gz::sim::systems::PosePublisher">
        <publish_link_pose>true</publish_link_pose>
        <use_pose_vector_msg>true</use_pose_vector_msg>
        <static_publisher>true</static_publisher>
        <static_update_frequency>1</static_update_frequency>
      </plugin>

      <plugin
        filename="gz-sim-odometry-publisher-system"
        name="gz::sim::systems::OdometryPublisher">
        <odom_frame>my_robot/odom</odom_frame>
        <robot_base_frame>my_robot</robot_base_frame>
      </plugin>
    </model>

  </world>
</sdf>


This is my robot's model file.
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<sdf version="1.8">
  <model canonical_link="base_link" name="my_robot">
    <!-- BASE -->
    <link name="base_link">
      <must_be_base_link>true</must_be_base_link>
    </link>
    <!-- CHASSIS -->
    <joint name="chassis_joint" type="fixed">
      <parent>base_link</parent>
      <child>chassis_link</child>
      <pose relative_to="base_link">0 0 0.075 0 0 0</pose>
    </joint>
    <link name="chassis_link">
      <pose relative_to="chassis_joint"/>
      <visual name="chassis_link_visual">
        <geometry>
          <box>
            <size>
                0.3 0.3 0.15
              </size>
          </box>
        </geometry>
        <material>
          <script>
            <uri> file://media/materials/scripts/gazebo.material </uri>
            <name> Gazebo/White </name>
          </script>
        </material>
      </visual>
      <collision name="chassis_link_collision">
        <geometry>
          <box>
            <size>
                0.3 0.3 0.15
              </size>
          </box>
        </geometry>
      </collision>
      <inertial>
        <mass>0.5</mass>
        <inertia>
          <ixx>0.0046875</ixx>
          <ixy>0.0</ixy>
          <ixz>0.0</ixz>
          <iyy>0.0046875</iyy>
          <iyz>0.0</iyz>
          <izz>0.0075</izz>
        </inertia>
      </inertial>
    </link>
    <!-- lEFT WHEEL -->
    <joint name="left_wheel_joint" type="revolute">
      <parent>base_link</parent>
      <child>left_wheel_link</child>
      <pose relative_to="base_link">0.09 0.16999999999999998 0 -1.5707963267948966 0 0</pose>
      <axis>
        <xyz>0 0 1</xyz>
        <limit>
          <lower>-inf</lower>
          <upper>inf</upper>
        </limit>
      </axis>
    </joint>
    <link name="left_wheel_link">
      <pose relative_to="left_wheel_joint"/>
      <visual name="left_wheel_link_visual">
        <geometry>
          <cylinder>
            <radius>0.05</radius>
            <length>0.04</length>
          </cylinder>
        </geometry>
        <material>
          <script>
            <uri> file://media/materials/scripts/gazebo.material </uri>
            <name> Gazebo/Blue </name>
          </script>
        </material>
      </visual>
      <collision name="left_wheel_link_collision">
        <geometry>
          <cylinder>
            <radius>0.05</radius>
            <length>0.04</length>
          </cylinder>
        </geometry>
      </collision>
      <inertial>
        <mass>0.1</mass>
        <inertia>
          <ixx>7.583333333333335e-05</ixx>
          <ixy>0.0</ixy>
          <ixz>0.0</ixz>
          <iyy>7.583333333333335e-05</iyy>
          <iyz>0.0</iyz>
          <izz>0.00012500000000000003</izz>
        </inertia>
      </inertial>
    </link>
    <!-- CASTER -->
    <joint name="caster_joint" type="fixed">
      <parent>base_link</parent>
      <child>caster_link</child>
      <pose relative_to="base_link">-0.09 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
    </joint>
    <link name="caster_link">
      <pose relative_to="caster_joint"/>
      <visual name="caster_link_visual">
        <geometry>
          <sphere>
            <radius>0.05</radius>
          </sphere>
        </geometry>
        <material>
          <script>
            <uri> file://media/materials/scripts/gazebo.material </uri>
            <name> Gazebo/Blue </name>
          </script>
        </material>
      </visual>
      <collision name="caster_link_collision">
        <geometry>
          <sphere>
            <radius>0.05</radius>
          </sphere>
        </geometry>
      </collision>
      <inertial>
        <mass>0.1</mass>
        <inertia>
          <ixx>0.00010000000000000002</ixx>
          <ixy>0.0</ixy>
          <ixz>0.0</ixz>
          <iyy>0.00010000000000000002</iyy>
          <iyz>0.0</iyz>
          <izz>0.00010000000000000002</izz>
        </inertia>
      </inertial>
    </link>
  </model>
</sdf>

I did not encounter these errors before adding collision tags to the robot's model file.

I found the fix to this issue. 
The fix is to change <self_collide>true</self_collide> to <self_collide>false</self_collide> or remove it entirely. 
The issue was that the robot's links were colliding with each other, and because of too many collisions, the ODE error happened. 
Another way to fix this is to make the chassis the parent of the wheels and caster (instead of the base_link), as links connected by a joint do not collide.
